# Importar CSV no SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, csv

Eu tentei importar uma base de dados utilizando o csv para uma base pronta do sql server que nós implantamos para outras empresas.

Mas no sistema quando se cadastra, um cliente por exemplo, utiliza-se do MAX(ID)+1 pra gerar o Id para determinada tabela.
Agora quando eu tento importar esses dados novos que estão em csv, o id fica nulo e por ser chave primária não deixa fazer a importação.

Como eu posso realizar esse Max(id) para definir o id da tabela na importação do arquivo csv.

Comment: Altere o tipo do campo para IDENTITY e exclua a coluna do arquivo CSV

Comment: A importação é executada em modo exclusivo, isto é, somente ela acessando a tabela? Qual o número aproximado de registros do arquivo CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer a importação do arquivo CSV para uma tabela temporária e a partir desta tabela temporária fazer a inclusão na tabela definitiva usando algo como

```
-- código #1
declare @Ultimo int;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT top (1) @Ultimo= id
  from tabela with (tablockx)
  order by id desc;

INSERT into tabela with (tablockx) (id, demais colunas)
  SELECT @Ultimo + row_number() over (order by (SELECT 0)),
         demais colunas
    from #tabelatemp;

COMMIT;
```

É uma sugestão que você deve avaliar se o bloqueio da tabela é obtido ou não.

É preciso ficar atento ao crescimento do log de transações enquanto a importação estiver em andamento.

Caso queira que o valor gerado para "id" seja segundo a ordem de algum campo do arquivo CSV, substitua `(SELECT 0)` pelo nome da respectiva coluna na tabela temporária.

É posível importar diretamente do arquivo texto para a tabela ao substituir `#tabelatemp` por `OPENROWSET (BULK ...)`. Detalhes no artigo “[Importação de dados em massa](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)”.